# .bat to Move Files

Tags: batch-file, move

I could use some assistance creating a batch file to move files into folders. I have tried looking at other batch files and figuring out the code myself but my situation is a bit unique so i thought i would be best served coming here from the start:
I have anywhere from 30,000 - 140,000 files (never an exact number may be 78,379 files as an example) in a directory.   I need to then take those files and split into sub folders with 5,000 files in each sub folder.   The file names are not anything like 1,2,3,4 or anything that easy - most of them are 8 digit file names such as 30024645.csv   but they are not consecutive so from that file the next one in line could be 30024759.csv    --- i am not looking to organize these files by any other way than just 5k per subfolder.

Comment: I am certain that there are examples of this already answered, so what exactly is the issue you are experiencing? Without showing us your code, and how it is failing to work as expected, your question reads as an off topic code request. Please ensure that you've taken the [tour], and read through the linked pages under [ask]. Then based upon that information, and  the rest of my comment, [edit] your question to something more answerable witihin the guidelines.

Comment: And please provide a [mcve] of your code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is one counter for keeping track of how many files you've moved, one counter for keeping track of which folder you're moving the files to, and a `for` loop to iterate over the files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source_folder=<REPLACE_ME>"
set "dest_root_folder=<REPLACE_ME>"
set "files_per_folder=5000"
set "current_folder=1"
set "file_count=0"

for %%A in ("%source_folder%\*") do (
    set /a file_count+=1
    if not exist "%dest_root_folder%\!current_folder!\" mkdir "%dest_root_folder%\!current_folder!\"
    move "%%A" "%dest_root_folder%\!current_folder!\%%~nxA" >nul
    
    if "!file_count!"=="!files_per_folder!" (
        set file_count=0
        set /a current_folder+=1
    )
)
```

Note that this solution will fail for any files that contain exclamation points in their filenames.